# Why does my code work in the REPL but not in the text editor (VSCode)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code, svelte

I'm doing a flashcard bit (these are all just made up words and definitions), and it works flawlessly in the REPL, but when I try to get it to work in VSCode, it gets all buggy — the cards flip on hover (like it's supposed to), but the back of the card is just the mirror of what's on the front, even though I have backface-visibility:hidden in the CSS. Here's the code:

```
<script>
    let zoushEntries = ["mugwort", "noice", "smolb", "gar", "hirum", "sion", "shlep", "akudema", "akilmda", "alsun", "rhema", "pith", 
"hrish","arnik", "yesop", "vsu", "slump", "fado"];
    let zoushIPA = ["[məgwɚt]", "[noice]","[smulb]" ];
    let zoushGloss = ["the semi-sweet rind of a melon", "To be full, to the point of discomfort","a loogie once it has hit the ground", "pirate affirmative; derivative of 'yar'", "to hold fast, steady", "a piece of cloth", "when there is no alternative", "i will be glad", "it's in my mind", "to dig deeper into a vat", "a tree that talks back", "the sagging bit of rotten gums", "the sound of stars sundering", "sweat glands", "fable man", "muffled voices from a further room", "to be as a moth to a flame", "to sing to the sea where a ship used to be" ];
    
    function showMore() {
        var dots = document.getElementById("dots");
        var revealedText = document.getElementById("more");
        var btnText = document.getElementById("myBtn");
        
        if (dots.style.display === "none"){
            dots.style.display = "inline";
            btnText.innerHTML = "Show more";
            revealedText.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            dots.style.display = "none";
            btnText.innerHTML = "Show less";
            revealedText.style.display = "inline";
        }
    }
    
    function clicked() {
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName('thecard')[0];
            x.style.transform = 'rotateY(180deg)';
    }
    
</script>


<style>
    :global(body) {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    .maincontainer {
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: inline-flex;
        position: relative;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
    }
    
    .thecard{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        
    }
    
    #more {
        display:none;
    }
    
    .thecard:hover{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    
    
    
    .thefront{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        color: #333;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    .theback{
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        color: white;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 17px;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

    
</style>

<svelte:head>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</svelte:head>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard" on:click={clicked}>
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[0]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg" >{zoushGloss[0]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[1]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[1]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[2]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[2]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[3]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg" >{zoushGloss[3]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[4]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[4]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[5]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[5]}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[6]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg" >{zoushGloss[6]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[7]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[7]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[8]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[8]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[9]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg" >{zoushGloss[9]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[10]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[10]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[11]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[11]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<span id="dots"><br>...</span><span id="more">

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[12]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[12]}</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[13]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[13]}</div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[14]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[14]}</div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[15]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[15]}</div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[16]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushGloss[16]}</div>
    </div>
</div>
    
    <div class="maincontainer">
    <div class="thecard">
        <div class="thefront flex p-6 bg-blue-200 shadow-lg rounded-lg">{zoushEntries[17]}</div>
        <div class="theback flex p-6 bg-teal-300 shadow-lg rounded-lg" >{zoushGloss[17]}</div>
    </div>
</div>
    
</span><br><br>
<button on:click={showMore} id="myBtn" class="text-white bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-400 rounded-sm p-1">Show more</button>
```

Comment: Add the code in a code snippet, and please include your entire code to check if the problem exists here.

Comment: Can you share your package.json file so we can see what your IDE is running?

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

You should change `.thecard:hover { ... }`  for `.maincontainer:hover .thecard { ... }`. Here's the [working REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/35411bae6725486894f9afc34aaeb21f?version=3.24.0).

**Long answer**

This is not a problem with REPL vs. IDE. Here's the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/b36f28d8561745d7a12bd1f755d72683?version=3.24.0) with your code. It doesn't work flawlessly. The rotation flickers on every hover. The back of the card is not always the front but, when it happens, it's because it rotated more than once.

When you rotate `.thecard` on hover, then it rotates a little bit, gets out of mouse focus, and then enters again on mouse focus. This new entrance is itself a new hover that triggers yet another rotation.

You need to set the hover listener on the parent `.maincontainer` which never rotates, thus never exists mouse focus, and therefore never flickers with subsequent transforms.

[credits](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_flip_card)